# Is there a way to stream tweets using python only for specific time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I'm working on tweepy to stream tweets.

As far I know we can start the streamer and leave it running indefinitely to work with tweets.

I was looking for a way to limit this stream and exit the streamer after some time like 10 minutes or so which we can specify.

From the docs, I couldn't find anything to do so. (I may have missed too.)

How do I specify the amount of time that the streamer can keep listening to the tweets.

```
import json

from tweepy import StreamListener, OAuthHandler, Stream


class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hashtag_frequency = {}

    def on_data(self, data):
        hashtags = json.loads(data)["entities"]["hashtags"]
        for hashtag in hashtags:
            text = hashtag["text"]
            self.hashtag_frequency[text] = self.hashtag_frequency.get(text, 1) + 1
        print(self.hashtag_frequency)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


listener = StdOutListener()
auth = OAuthHandler('', '')
auth.set_access_token('', '')

stream = Stream(auth, listener)

stream.filter(track=['testing'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a timer in there, something like and just add a `break` at the end of it

```py
import time
t = #Add number of seconds you want the bot to run, if you want 10 minutes, than it's 600 seconds
if t != 0: 
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60) 
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs) 
        print(timer, end="\r")  
        t -= 1
else:
     return
```

Comment: But, I'm not using  a while loop here. It is just the filter() method which is taking care of stuff.

Comment: Oh, in that case, just add a condition, that would say that ```if t =0: break```